# "mv" apparently deleted my script!

Tags: bash

My command was:

```
mv count_entries.py ~/journal_tools/
```

Now the file is missing from both ~ and /journal_tools/...

If it matters, I was logged in as a user without administrative rights, and ~ is a Dropbox directory, "Projects."

Comment: ~ = your home directory, try looking there

Comment: tilda is your HOME folder not Dropbox (at least in Terminal). Look in journal_tools in home directory. If journal_tools did not exist before on home directory may happen  that your file is now called joural_tools

Comment: In terminal ~ is not your Dropbox directory ~ will actually forward the path to: /home/USERNAME. In this case, you have moved your script to /home/USERNAME/journal_tools (if that folder actually exists, if not then the file is where it was before).

Comment: Try `find ~ -name count_entries` (you may need to wait a bit).

Answer (score 1):

`count_entries.py` is now at `~/journal_tools/count_entries.py` where `~` is expanded to the home directory of the current user at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I found it just now in /home/[current user] where it had been renamed to "journal_tools". OK, thanks folks!